# How to convert string to int32 to hex and store into buffer

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a string to string and then to hex. The string value represent for example an integer like 266. The main reason why I do this, I store all my values in the string and want send them over network to a host, therefore I must represent all values as hex. If I convert string "`266`" to int32 and then to hex "`0x010a`" and store the hex value in a buffer, the buffer contains "`30 31`" and not 0x010a. Here is an running example of my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <stdint.h> /* int32_t*/
#include <stdlib.h> /* strtol, malloc */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy */

int integer_to_hex(
        char **out_hex,
        int *out_len,
        int32_t value)
{
    *out_len = 0;
    *out_hex = NULL;
    if ( value < 128 && value > -128)
    {
        *out_len = 1;
        *out_hex = malloc(*out_len);
        sprintf(*out_hex,"%02x", value & 0xff);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (value < 32767 && value > -32767)
    {
        *out_len = 2;
        *out_hex = malloc(*out_len);
        sprintf(*out_hex,"%04x", value);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char *value_str = "266";
    int32_t val_int = strtol(value_str,NULL,10);
    char *out_hex;
    int out_len;
    int ret_val = integer_to_hex(&out_hex, &out_len, val_int);
    printf("ret_val=%d\n", ret_val);
    printf("out=%s\n", out_hex);
    printf("out_len=%d\n", out_len);
    char *buffer = malloc(out_len);
    memcpy(&buffer, &out_hex, out_len);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<out_len;i++)
        printf("buffer=%02x\n", buffer[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
ret_val=0
out=010a
out_len=2
buffer=30
buffer=31
```

Comment: `30 31` are the first two hex digits `0` and `1` in ASCII. A single hex digit needs a whole byte if you encode it as characters.

Comment: @FelixPalmen you are right, but I don't know how?

Comment: What do you mean by "hex"? A number stored as hexadecimal *string*? If so, your buffer allocations are way too small.

Comment: how what? .. :o

Comment: In a nutshell, your function converts the number to a hex representation as a string (let aside writing out of bounds!) and then you look at the individual characters of the string, converting their numerical code to a hex representation **again**.

Comment: `int32_t val_int = strtol(value_str,NULL,10);` This already does all the job. There's no "int32" format and there's no "hex" format. The only two formats actually present in a program is text (ASCII) and binary. `strtol` converts from text to binary. So what are you trying to do, convert a decimal string to a binary string? What do you mean with "hex"?

Comment: @user694733 yes, a number as hexadecimal string  e.g.: "`01 0a`" in a char buffer

Comment: Seems a lot of effort for no reason - you can send the string "266" as is over the network

Comment: Why don't you think you can send a string? A string is just a sequence of bytes!

Comment: @ChrisTurner you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem *seems* to be a fundamental misunderstanding that a number could be stored "as hex". A computer always stores numbers in binary.

Showing a number in hexadecimal is just convenient because a group of four binary digits (bits) exactly matches one single hexadecimal digit (`0`-`f`).

But if you want the computer to show you hexadecimal digits on the screen, the only way is to encode these digits as characters. On your typical ASCII-based implementation, each character takes eight(!) bits.

When you read the number 266, what gets stored in the lower 16 bits of your `uint32_t` is

```
0000 0001 0000 1010
   0    1    0    a     (mapping to hex)
```

If you want to *display* this, you need the **characters** `0`, `1` and `a`, which are encoded in ASCII as `30 (0011 0000)`, `31 (0011 0001)` and `61 (0110 0001)`. The `printf()` family of functions with a `%x` format specifier does this conversion. This gives you

```
   3    0 |    3    1 |    3    0 |    6    1      (mapping to hex)
0011 0000 | 0011 0001 | 0011 0000 | 0110 0001      (four `char`)
```

Your code in the question now takes the individual bytes of this character string (interpreted as numbers!) and converts to a hex string again!

Answer (score 0):

Converting from a string with a decimal number to a string with a hex number is fairly trivial if you use standard library functions. Simply strip away most of the code from your program and you'll end up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define LARGE_ENOUGH (8+1)

int main (void) 
{
  const char str_dec[] = "266";
  char str_hex [LARGE_ENOUGH];

  int32_t binary = strtol(str_dec, NULL, 10);
  sprintf(str_hex, "%.4"PRIX32, binary);

  puts(str_hex);
}
```

There's no obvious reason why you need to use malloc().